# Text appears in two lines when browser width gets smaller

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, styles

My issue is that the text starts to appear in two lines when browser width gets a little smaller.

I am using the bootstrap grid system... so shouldn't the text be adjusted within the grid?

I tried changing:

```
<div class="row">
```

To

```
<div class="row col-sm-12">
```

but same result.

My code snippet:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <p>Posted by admin on this this date</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <p class="text-right"><a href="#">One comment</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot of issue:

[image]

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x9g2th82/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `sm` to `xs`.

So now your code look like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <p>Posted by admin on this this date</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <p class="text-right"><a href="#">One comment</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You have to read the [Bootstrap CSS documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) first. It is clearly stated that `.col-sm-` column prefix will work starting from the width of Small Devices Tablets (≥768px).

Answer (score 1):

Like Rizki said. You need to change col-sm-4 and col-sm-8 to this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <p>
      Posted by admin on this this date</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <p class="align-right"><a href="#">One comment</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check it out in action -- https://jsfiddle.net/aLuv47bt/

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Change col-sm tp col-xs to make it in one line. Here is the code.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <p>Posted by admin on this this date</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <p class="text-right"><a href="#">One comment</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

simple fix this with `white-space:nowrap`

```
p {
 white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```css
p {
  white-space:nowrap;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <p>
      Posted by admin on this this date</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <p class="text-right"><a href="#">One comment</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Check with demo**

https://jsfiddle.net/x9g2th82/4/

Comment: doesn't seem to fix it